# AIP conference proceedings template conflict with float package

Tags: floats

When i include `\usepackage{float}` in my document i get this error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \float@box already defined.
```

My preample with the float package:

```
\documentclass{aip-cp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[greek.polutoniko,english]{babel}
\usepackage{babelbib}
\selectbiblanguage{english}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
%My paper
\end{document}
```

Is there a conflict between AIP conference proceedings template and float package? Is there anything else that causes the problem?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! I guess it is already defined in `aip-cp.cls`.

Comment: If it was the case, I think i would be able to use the H symbol as a floating option for a figure. I can't.

Comment: It sounds like the only part of the `float` package you use is the `[H]` placement specifier. Have you considered not loading the `float` package at all and replacing all instances of `[H]` with `[ht!]`?